# Reusing a MQQueueManger in a Distributed Transaction in .NET

Tags: .net, transactions, ibm-mq

I'm writing a .NET application using `TransactionScope` [.Net transactions]. The code is a simple loop using the same `MQQueueManager` instance:

- receive from a Topic subscription
- save to MSSQL db
- send translated message to another Topic
- commit transaction

When I get to the top of the loop to get the new message, I get a `MQRC_GLOBAL_UOW_CONFLICT` exception.

I understand that transaction commit is asynchronous and the queue manager might not be ready yet to participate in a new transaction. How do I determine that it is ready? I subscribed to the `TransactionCompleted` event on `Transaction.Current` and waited for that to fire before re-entering the loop. Same exception. I was able to avoid the exception by sleeping for 10 milliseconds, but I don't want to put hard timeouts on this. There must be a 'proper' way to know.

The Code:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool tranDone = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "server");
        properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
        properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
        MQQueueManager mgr = new MQQueueManager("QManager", properties);

        MQTopic topicIn = mgr.AccessTopic("TopicString", "TopicName",
            MQC.MQSO_DURABLE | MQC.MQSO_RESUME | MQC.MQSO_MANAGED | MQC.MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING,
            null, "SubscriptionName");

        MQTopic topicOut = mgr.AccessTopic(
            "TopicString2", "TopicName",
            MQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_PUBLICATION,
            MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

        MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions
        {
            Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT,
            // 1 minute wait
            WaitInterval = 1000 * 60
        };


        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions
        {
            Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT,
        };



        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += Current_TransactionCompleted;

                    MQMessage msgIn = new MQMessage();

                    topicIn.Get(msgIn, gmo);
                    string text = msgIn.ReadString(msgIn.MessageLength);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message Received: {text}");

                    MQMessageContext context = new MQMessageContext();
                    context.Messages.Add(new Message() { Content = text });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Added to DB");

                    MQMessage msgOut = new MQMessage();
                    string ttext = $"translated: {text}";
                    msgOut.WriteString(ttext);
                    topicOut.Put(msgOut, pmo);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message Sent: {ttext}");

                    msgIn.ClearMessage();

                    Console.Write("Commit? [Y/N/Q]: ");
                    string response = Console.ReadLine();

                    if ("y" == response.ToLower())
                    {
                        ts.Complete();
                        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Committed");
                    }
                    else if ("q" == response.ToLower())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Quitting");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            when (MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE == mqe.ReasonCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Msg not available in interval");
                continue;
            }

            while (!tranDone)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2);
            }

            tranDone = false;
        }

    }

    private static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
    {
        tranDone = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Posting your code may help to understand the problem better

Comment: What other resource apart from MQ are you putting into your global transaction? i.e. why are you using global transactions instead of just an MQ only transaction?

Comment: @MoragHughson Microsoft SQLServer. The MQMessageContext carries the database connection and commits on context.SaveChanges()

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041280_.htm

Comment: @Shashi. I'm not having issues connecting to the queue manager. Not sure what to look for in the page you linked.

Comment: Looks like I am having bad day today. Sorry about the incorrect link. Here is the correct one: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q043800_.htm

Comment: yes, I've read through the error spec. It does not mention how to determine whether my 'connection handle' is already participating in a global unit of work. Also, what is a 'connection handle' - QueueManager or Topic/Queue?

Answer (score 0):

Connection handle (or HCONN) basically represents a connection to queue manager. It is abstracted by `MQQueueManager` class in OO languages like C#. Languages like C provides access to HCONN.

MQ tracks the transactions on a per connection basis. So my suggestion to you would be to create a new connection for every transaction to avoid `MQRC_GLOBAL_UOW_CONFLICT` error. Make sure to close the connection after completing the transaction.

Comment: how expensive is it to reconnect and re-access the topics and subscriptions?

Comment: There is cost involved definitely as existing objects, connection needs to be closed and new ones created for every new transaction.